# Accessing user_ID via messenger bot

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API, but I can't figure out how to get a logged-in users ID address.

The intro to Graph states "The Graph API can provide access to all of the basic account registration data you would typically request in a sign-up form for your site, including name, email address, profile picture, and birthday" but to access them i need user_ID so how could i get it ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v3.0

You need to have a token from the user, check out the given link. You can see what informations you can access if you give permission to your own profile.
**This ID is unique to each app and cannot be used across different apps.**

Comment: Ok, but how could i get access to token from user in messenger bot ?